# Meta keybindings for bash readline from .inputrc not working

Tags: bash, readline, inputrc

If I put

```
"\M-p": previous-history
```

into my .inputrc and fire up a terminal (urxvt or xterm), hitting Alt-p prints a ":" character. Subsequent hits produce ^[p like so:

```
:^[p^[p^[p^[p^[p
```

I would like for Alt-p to give me the previous command in history as Control-p does. I have verified that .inputrc is being read by binding previous-history to Control-t, and that worked.

```
"\C-t": previous-history
```

I have also tried

```
Meta-p: previous-history
```

with no success.

Has anyone else had this issue? Am I doing something wrong? 
I'm on Debian sid using xmonad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding

```
set convert-meta on
```

enabled me to set bindings like:

Meta-r: kill-line
Meta-r: kill-line

Comment: Added that line to the top of my .inputrc, followed by `Meta-p: previous-history` and `Meta-n: next-history` did the trick. Thanks!